# Step over , step into and step buttons are disabled in chrome browser (debugging mode)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, debugging

I am trying to debug java script in chrome. But i see that step over , step into and step buttons are disabled hence i am unable to continue with debugging.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set breakpoints in your code already? If yes, then your program is not stepping into that code.

Comment: also where can i check the value of the variables ( while in debugging mode). I use chrome as my browser

Answer (score -1):

Go to source in developer tools at the top right corner you will find setting button, click on it and you will see source related category all check boxes, you have to enable the tab moves focus boom thats it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).